# ¿ Cual es el mejor Tipo de dato para una descripción?

Tags: base-de-datos

estoy realizando una base de datos para un agencia de viajes. Quería saber ¿ Cual es el mejor Tipo de dato para una descripción de un destino ?. ejemplo: La ciudadela es una zona arqueológica...

Answer (score 1):

Depende de cuántos caracteres quieres poder almacenar en ese campo.

- TINYTEXT: 255 caracteres  UTF-8
- TEXT: 65,535 caracteres UTF-8
- MEDIUMTEXT: 16,777,215 caracteres UTF-8
- LONGTEXT: 4,294,967,295 caracteres UTF-8

Yo creo que con un TEXT te debe ser suficiente.

Comment: Gracias lo revisare !